# JavaFX - ContextMenu, ChoiceBox and ComboBox flickering

Tags: java, javafx

I am using the three components ContextMenu, ChoiceBox and ComboBox. I have the problem, when using them, the behaviour of the opened box seems buggy:

The blue highlighting of the box is flickering when I move the cursor. When the current entry is not selected (wrongly), the entry behind the popup is selected.

Does anyone else have experienced that problem?

(Additional information: I am using JDK 1.7.0_45 on 64Bit Ubuntu.)

Comment: Do you have appropriate graphics drivers installed ? Lack of which will render flickering

Comment: Even in Java 8, I am facing the same issue. The only way to select the items is by using the keyboard ! 
I am using 64bit xubuntu

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue on Linux Mint 15 (Cinamon), 64Bit + JDK 1.7.0_45. I have NVidia GF 330M (Optimus), no newer driver seem to be available on Linux.